# vercel cli cannot pick up specified config file (--local-config not working)

Tags: config, vercel

I use vercel cli to build app locally and then `vercel deploy --prebuilt` .
`Vercel CLI 28.16.15` - the latest version - still not working. Before this version tried `28.16.12` no luck as well.

For that I want to use command like `vercel --local-config vercel-dev.json build` as per documentation https://vercel.com/docs/cli/global-options#local-config

But it does not work 
json file ignored ‍♂️

I tried other names for json file like `vercel -A vercel/dev/vercel.json build` but still no success at all.

I need to use different buildCommand for different branch deployment
So, my `vercel.json` file looks like that:

```
{
  "buildCommand": "yarn build:dev"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why vercel cli cannot pick up specified config file?

P.S. it is not only about different env, but in general about `json` config with all the other options including buildCommand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed ✅.

It was the issue in CLI package itself, latest version `28.17.0` now works as expected due to merged PR https://github.com/vercel/vercel/pull/9675